# Can we use mongoose in mean stack project?

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to mean stack. I just seen a sample project in mean stack which worked for me. But can we use mongoose in mean stack project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use mongoose.

First you want to add the mongoose dependency to your package.json

There are two ways
 - Run **sudo npm install mongoose --save-dev** (it will automatically update package.json file)
 - manually type it in under dependencies - **"mongoose": "^4.11.7"**

Once that is done, add the dependency to your server.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Then add connection

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DBNAME', {
useMongoClient: true},
 function (err, db) {
if (!err) {
    console.log("We're connected to Mongo");
}
});
```

DBNAME - is the name of your database.